# How to extract Header and Footer section from openXML file?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have Open Xml file which has Header, Body and Footer content. When I am trying to insert that open Xml it always picking only Body related part and not able to extract Header & Footer section data out of it.

I tried below snippet, but it always printing Body part data instead of Header data which resides in Header1.xml

ps: WORD_OPEN_XML is holding whole content

```
async function insertHeader() {
    Word.run(async (context) => {
      const mySections = context.document.sections;
      context.load(mySections);
      await context.sync();
      for (let i = 0; i < mySections.items.length; i++) {
        mySections.items[i].getHeader('Primary').insertOoxml(WORD_OPEN_XML, 'Replace');
      }
      await context.sync();
    });
  }
```

Please help me to insert Header and Footer part from that open Xml
[WORD_OPEN_XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ7ca.png)

Comment: cc @juan-balmori

Comment: I'm wondering if this has anything to do w/ Office Add-Ins? Or is this just JS related?